# Atom Editor autocomplete-clang for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, autocomplete, editor, clang, atom-editor

I'm really new to the Atom editor. I am trying hard to get the package autocomplete-clang to work. Had played around with some things, but nothing does it the right way.
What works are the C-based APIs like CoreGraphics autocompletion. But when I try to write [NSMutableDi ...], from the Foundation classes, nothing happens. What do I have to configure, to get it to work?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Try popping up autocomplete, IIRC it's Ctrl+Space.